# How to add a break between Array objects with knockout and tooltip

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I have an array joined with commas in a tooltip. However I want each one be on it's own line. I've tried a few things but none seem to be working. The code is a knockout observable to which I am new too.

Here is my ko observable:

```
 this.campaignTagString = ko.observable("");
(function() {
    if(data.campaignTags != undefined) {
        var array = [];
        for(var tag in data.campaignTags){
            array.push(data.campaignTags[tag].name);
        }
        //Join our campaign tag name array
        var tagString = array.join(", " + '<br />');
        $('#tooltip-campaigntags').tooltip({ 
          content: function(callback) { 
             callback($(this).prop('title').replace('|', '<br />')); 
          }
        });
        var textCampaign = "Campaigns: ";
        o.campaignTagString(textCampaign + tagString);
    }
})();
```

I am calling it like so:

```
<span id="tooltip-campaigntags" class="label label-default label-mini" data-bind="html: '<i class=\'fa fa-tags\'></i> '+campaignTags().length, tooltip: { title: campaignTagString , placement: 'bottom' }" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" >
</span>
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Instead of '\n' have you tried '<br/>'

Comment: I have tried <br/> yes, doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some tips:

- You have an error in your code: if `campaignTags` is an object, `campaignTags().length` will not work; if it is an array, `data.campaignTags[tag].name` will not work.
- You might find it useful to have a look at [Knockout-Bootstrap](http://billpull.com/knockout-bootstrap), a Bootstrap adaptation that provides Knockout bindingHandlers for Bootstrap JS functions (used in demo below).
- The Bootstrap documentation mentions the option `{html: true}` if you want your content not to be encoded into text.
- Additionally, your IIFE (the function in which you wrapped the bootstrap tooltip functionality) should rather be a computed observable on your view model, as well as the icon html, and the string, all depending on `campaignTags`.

Below are the resulting JS viewModel and HTML binding if you follow these tips:

```
//params === object containing tag objects like -- tagX: {name: 'tag'}
function VM(params) { 
    var self = this;
    this.campaignTags = params;
    this.campaignTagsArray = ko.computed(function() {
        var array = [];
        for(var tag in self.campaignTags) {
            array.push(self.campaignTags[tag].name);} 
        return array;});
    this.campaignTagString = ko.computed(function() { 
        return "Campaigns: <br>" + 
               self.campaignTagsArray().join(", " + '<br />'); });
    this.html = ko.computed(function() { 
        return '<i class="fa fa-tags"></i>&nbsp; ' + 
               self.campaignTagsArray().length });
}
```

And the HTML binding:

```
<span class="label label-default label-mini" data-bind="
     html: html(), 
     tooltip: { html: true, title: campaignTagString() , placement: 'bottom'}">
</span>
```

Check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/zmqr9he8/1/) for a demo.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm working with someone else's code so it's tricky. 

html:true wouldn't work but data-html="true" works and then takes in html